# Import json file into postgres table with single json column

Tags: json, postgresql, import

I have been trying to load a json file in postgres as a single json column.

**Table:**
`create table book(values json);`

The file looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "isbn": "846896359-3",
    "title": "Jungle Book 2, The",
    "price": 22.05,
    "date": "12/28/2017",
    "authors": [
      {
        "first": "Marlène",
        "last": "Ashley",
        "age": 38
      },
      {
        "first": "Miléna",
        "last": "Finley",
        "age": 37
      },
      {
        "first": "Stévina",
        "last": "Bullus",
        "age": 44
      }
    ],
    "publisher": {
      "name": "Youspan",
      "address": {
        "street": "Iowa",
        "number": "853",
        "city": "München",
        "country": "Germany"
      },
      "phone": "361-191-8111"
    }
  },
  {
    "isbn": "558973823-7",
    "title": "Star Trek III: The Search for Spock",
    "price": 36.58,
    "date": "4/19/2017",
    "authors": [
      {
        "first": "Uò",
        "last": "Ibel",
        "age": 26
      },
      {
        "first": "Mélys",
        "last": "Grasner",
        "age": 36
      },
      {
        "first": "Mylène",
        "last": "Laven",
        "age": 40
      },
      {
        "first": "Pò",
        "last": "Lapsley",
        "age": 37
      }
    ],
    "publisher": {
      "name": "Chatterbridge",
      "address": {
        "street": "Dennis",
        "number": "1",
        "city": "São Tomé",
        "country": "Sao Tome and Principe"
      },
      "phone": "845-226-0017"
    }
  }
]
```

Tried the copy command but it throws a `'Token "" is invalid.'` error. I have also tried a number of other solutions

Comment: Show the exact copy command you're using.

Comment: create table Books(values json);        
copy Books from 'BOOKS_DATA.json'; The file is in the data folder of postgres. The command works if I make the 'values' column text but not if it of type json.

Comment: Try setting a delimiter explicitly: `COPY books FROM 'BOOKS_DATA.json' DELIMITER '\`'` - sets it to a character that doesn't exist in your JSON, just to make sure it will treat the whole thing as one field rather than attempting to split it by some default character.

Comment: Tried this but it says - 'Token "" is invalid.' error

Comment: I edited my comment a couple times as it wasn't showing the character correctly, so make sure you're using what is currently shown - a delimiter of the \` (backtick) character in single quotes. I use that exact character all the time when copying to and from files, so I know it works. Alternatively put some other character in there - maybe | or something else that isn't used in your json.

Comment: It is not working. I'm using PgAdmin in Windows. Do you think I should try in cmdline?

Comment: I tried the backtick in single quotes but it is giving me an error. Also, I just tried it in ubuntu and I'm getting "invalid input syntax for type json. The input string ended unexpectedly" error. Also tried a bunch of other characters and nothing seems to work

Comment: Ok have a look at this instead http://adpgtech.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/importing-json-data.html Specifically the quote and delimiter bit. It always works for me the way I said above, because I export the JSON via COPY which probably escapes/quotes everything correctly, so I can import it without problem. In your case you may need a command more like the one in the link.

Comment: Tried the solution but that didn't work either. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

So, I finally got it to work. 
First I removed new line characters from the file using 
`tr -d '\n' < yourfile.txt`

Then I ran the following script:

```sql
create table Bookstemp(values text);                    

copy Bookstemp from 'BOOKS_DATANew.json';

create table books(valjson json);

Insert into books
select values
from   (
           select json_array_elements(replace(values,'\','\\')::json) as values 
           from   Bookstemp
       ) a;
```